# Udev & Xorg Connect Huion Tablet to Appropriate Driver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, drivers, udev, tablet

I am attempting to connect a Huion H610 Pro (8192) to my Arch Linux for full functionality. Currently it is only recognized by lsusb (ID 256c:006e), and is not associated with any drivers. The issue appears to be that libinput does not recognize this tablet, despite being stated to be supported, and others having success with it out of the box.

The physical device's LED lights up when buttons are pressed, pen is within range or touching work space. There also is output from `sudo usbhid-dump -es -m 256c:006e` when using the pen to draw on the tablet, however no response in the dump from button presses on the tablet. Output is as expected from [DIGImend troubleshoot webpage](https://digimend.github.io/support/howto/trbl/locating_failure/#tablet-hardware).

I have tried installing the following drivers from the Arch Linux official repository: xf86-input-libinput, xf86-input-evdev, xf86-input-wacom, and their corresponding libs.

I also have tried the Arch Unofficial Repository: digimend-kernel-drivers, wizardpen.

None of these work. I may need to do more than just install them such as give one more priority over another, but I have not found any sources on this. I have tried various combinations of installations with them too, although they do not appear to get in each other's way.

I have tried to follow [this answer's steps on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500141/huion-h610-tablet#answer-854842), and have successfully set up a symlink to the hidraw, however I cannot get Xorg to connect this symlinked input event to an InputDevice and corresponding Driver.

---

**Anyone know how I should set up the udev rules and xorg conf to appropriately connect this device to a driver (preferably libinput or wacom)?**

---

### Details / Troubleshooting

dmesg output once connected:

```
$ sudo dmesg
[  162.687139] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  162.828474] usb 1-10: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 1 but max is 0
[  162.828478] usb 1-10: config 1 has no interface number 0
[  162.832150] input: NUVOTON WPM USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1/0003:0416:A316.0006/input/input20
[  162.887749] hid-generic 0003:0416:A316.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [NUVOTON WPM USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1
[  166.053899] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  166.377593] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  166.576102] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: device parameters not found
[  166.576105] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: tablet enabling failed
[  166.576170] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0008: No inputs registered, leaving
[  166.576221] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0008: hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 256c:006e] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1
[  166.588904] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: device parameters not found
[  166.588907] uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: tablet enabling failed
```

Lines added to udev for creating sysmlink, [as stated here](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Fixed_device_files_with_udev):
(modified copy overrides /usr/lib/share/udev/rules.d/wacom.rules)

/etc/udev/rules.d/wacom.rules

```
### Add support for HUION tablet here:
ATTRS{idVendor}=="256c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="006e", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-huion"
# Check and repossess the device if a module other than the wacom one
# is already bound to it.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="256c", ACTION=="add", RUN+="check_driver wacom $devpath $env{ID_BUS}"
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-huion.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Huion_on_wacom_class"
    Driver "wacom"
    #MatchIsTablet "on" # disabled because I don't think this is recognized
    #MatchProduct "HUION" # same as IsTablet
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/tablet-huion" # using symlink from udev
    #MatchUSBID "256c:006e" # tried this too, to no avail
EndSection
```

$ [udevadm monitor --environment](https://gist.github.com/prijatelj/1c3e3578c4de172e07503ea08bb116a1)

---

[I submitted an issue on DIGImend's github](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/issues/106): More troubleshooting details provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Judging from

```
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: device parameters not found
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: tablet enabling failed
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0008: No inputs registered, leaving
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0008: hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 256c:006e] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: device parameters not found
uclogic 0003:256C:006E.0007: tablet enabling failed
```

it looks like the `hid-uclogic` driver is not working with your tablet. In particular, it's *not* registering a kernel input device, which is why you don't see any events past the HID layer.

(As a reminder, the event chain is: USB (kernel) -> HID (kernel) -> input (kernel) -> xf86-input-evdev/xf86-input-libinput (X driver) -> X).

Things to try:

- Blacklist the `hid-uclogic` kernel module, and see if you get at least some automatically translated HID events by the default kernel translator. Apparently a special driver is needed, so it won't be perfect or may not work at all, but it *may* be at least partly usable.
- Update your kernel to the newest version.
- Try to update `hid-uclogic` to some newer version, using out of tree [kernel patches](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-patches) or [kernel drivers](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers)

More debugging help: You can use `evtest` once you get a kernel input layer device, and `xev` or `xinput` for X events. I recommend using `evdev` over `libinput`, because it's the older and more stable method.